# Dynamic Transpose two columns from a table

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, xml

I have a web data source that I can query through the URL, but the data that comes back is not playing very nicely in excel. It looks like:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Assets total="8" pageSize="2147483647" pageStart="0">
    <Asset href="relativePath" id="89412">
        <Attribute name="Name">Torqbar</Attribute>
        <Attribute name="Number">PSU-3323</Attribute>
        <Attribute name="CreateDate">2013-07-17T13:54:43.907</Attribute>
        <Attribute name="IsSold">true</Attribute>
        <Attribute name="DoneDate">2013-07-24T11:04:26.577</Attribute>
    </Asset>
</Assets>`

This is great, because I can add columns, for example if I want to get back *ListedDate* all I have to do is add that to the query and then I will get back an attribute with *ListedDate* as the name, and the value of that node as the listed date.

But when excel opens this data, it doesn't know to treat the attribute nodes as columns. So I get this back:[image: screen cap of excel files where attribute nodes are rows instead of desired columns]

Is there a way to transpose this data easily? I know I could transform this data but that seems painful for this task, I would really love to hand this spread sheet over to novice computer users, explain how they can change the URL and then have the spreadsheet

1. Find the distinct set of `name` values in the `name` column
2. Transpose the data from those rows into column

So it would look like[image: properly formatted table with attributes as columns instead of key/value pair rows]

Comment: Is there always only a single item (Name)? in the returned query?

Comment: No there are N number. It varies.

Comment: I think the "easiest" way will be to transform the data.  Either with Power Query or with a custom VBA solution; and then use a button or user form as the "trigger" for your novice computer users

Answer (score 0):

Once you have repeating values for some columns and no for others you can use VBA code to do it or you can use a Pivot Table + Formulae to do that.

I've created a sample for you using Pivot Table + Formulae [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nrc2bbnsrf8h1v3/Dynamic%20Transpose%20two%20columns%20from%20a%20table.xlsx?dl=0).